# Undefined variable: respuesta in file

Tags: php, laravel, response

he tenido el problema reflejado en el título. Al hacer una petición en la que quiero que se modifique un empleado, quiero que dependiendo de qué sea lo que ocurra, me de un mensaje diciendo una cosa u otra. Entiendo que la variable $respuesta está fuera de rango(?). Esto ya me había pasado en otros lenguajes de programación y declarando la variable al principio suele ser suficiente pero realmente no me doy cuenta de lo que está mal con este código. Como que la variable se queda en el if y solo se le puede hacer referencia ahí o algo por el estilo. Dejo a continuación el código a ver si alguien puede echarme una mano:

```
  public function modificarEmpleado(Request $req){
    
    $datos = $req->getContent();
    $datos = json_decode($datos);
    $correo = $req->input('correo', '');
    $peticiario = User::where('api_token', $datos->api_token)->first();
    $usuario = User::where('email', $correo)->first();
    
    if($peticiario->puesto == "directivo"){//el peticiario es directivo 
        if($usuario->puesto == "directivo"){//el usuario es directivo tambien
            if($usuario->email == $peticiario->email){//el usuario es la misma persona que hace la petición
                if(isset($datos->name))
                $usuario->name = $datos->name;

                if(isset($datos->name))
                $usuario->puesto = $datos->puesto;

                if(isset($datos->name))
                $usuario->password = Hash::make($datos->password);
        
                if(isset($datos->name))
                $usuario->email = $datos->email;
            
                if(isset($datos->name))
                $usuario->salario = $datos->salario;

                if(isset($datos->name))
                $usuario->biografia = $datos->biografia;
    
                $usuario->save();
                $respuesta["msg"] = "Usuario editado con éxito";
                
            }else{//el usuario es otro directivo
                $respuesta["msg"] = "No puedes editar a otro directivo";
            }
        }     
    }
    if($peticiario->puesto == "RRHH"){//el peticiario es RRHH
           if($usuario->puesto == "empleado"){//el usuario es empleado
                if(isset($datos->name))
                    $usuario->name = $datos->name;

                if(isset($datos->name))
                    $usuario->puesto = $datos->puesto;

                if(isset($datos->name))
                    $usuario->password = Hash::make($datos->password);
        
                if(isset($datos->name))
                    $usuario->email = $datos->email;
            
                if(isset($datos->name))
                    $usuario->salario = $datos->salario;

                if(isset($datos->name))
                    $usuario->biografia = $datos->biografia;
    
                $usuario->save();
                $respuesta["msg"] = "Usuario editado con éxito";
           }else{
                $respuesta["msg"] = "Solo puedes editar a trabajadores que sean empleados";
           } 
    }
return response()->json($respuesta);
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde inicializás la variable _respuesta_? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Por tu código se puede dar el caso de que peticiario->puesto sea "empleado, verdad? Si es así, entonces ese caso no entraría en ninguno de los if, y no llegaría a definir la variable $respuesta, por lo que el return response de json no tendría definida esa variable y te daría error

Comment: @Jakala efectivamente es eso, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y tu comentario! vaya despiste...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres decir al mencionar `rango` es en realidad lo que se conoce como `scope` o `alcance` de una variable. Lo que haces aquí es declarar tu variable  dentro de las condiciones `IF`, lo cual no está mal, ya que sabemos que:

> In PHP, variables can be declared anywhere in the script.

Pero aquí estás usando condiciones que pueden o **no pueden** cumplirse. Si una de tus condiciones no se cumple, la variable `$resultados` nunca va a ser declarada y por ende obtendrás dicho error.

Te recomiendo o bien declarar la variable al inicio de la función, o asignarle un valor por default fuera de los `IF`, al final de la función. O por último, colocar un `ElSE` a cada `IF` para controlar la declaración de la variable.

Comment: Genial muchas gracias, efectivamente lo que no estaba consiguiendo es que entrara en ninguna condición y solo se lanzara $respuesta si edito un directivo si eres un directivo, no si haces algo distinto, muchas gracias, vaya despiste...